# How to parse a date like "9 October 2014 20:23:09 BST"

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I am wanting to parse a date, received from a webpage, in the form `9 October 2014 20:23:09` or `9 October 2014 20:23:09 BST` (or `EST` etc)

```
    protected DateTime ExtractFullDate(string date)
    {
        DateTime result = DateTime.MinValue;
        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "d M yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
        {
             // Always fails and gets here
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong with the format specifiers but it always fails the `TryParseExact`. I have tried variations of `MM` & `MMM` for the month, but no difference.

Comment: I don't think DateTime can parse time zone abbreviations. You might have to replace those with offsets, like `date = date.Replace("EST", "+07");`

Comment: You can use [literal string delimiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for your `BST` or `EST` part. But in such a case, you need to use other `DateTime.TryParseExact` overload which takes formats as a string array.

Comment: @Soner Gönül: That does solve the final problem quite nicely. An array of multiple format strings is fine for this problem. Feel free to list an expanded answer for upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `MMMM` and `HH` format strings, as specified here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx. `M` is for the numeric month 1-12, `hh` is for a 12 hour clock.

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
```

You'll need a separate parser if you want the timezone offset, though. AFAIK there's no format string for time zone names like `EST` so you might have to convert it to the UTC offset.

Answer (score 2):

Use this format: "d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Argh... It was actually the `HH` I was going wrong on! I had already tried `MMMM` Well done.

Answer (score 1):

You have already accepted an answer but I want to add some informations which didn't mentioned on other answers. It can be repetition but I want to add complete answer. Here my [two cents](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_cents#Noun):

From [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly.**

When we look at your formats, [`"M"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier) represents your month as a number from `1` through `12`. But you are using your month as a full name of month which fits with [`"MMMM"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMMM_Specifier).

[`"hh"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) for *12-hour clock* which is 01 through `12`. But you are using `20` as an hour which is *24-hour clock*. And that's why it fits with [`"HH"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) which is for `00` to `23`.

```
string s = "9 October 2014 20:23:09";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Successful parse
}
```

Let's look at to parse time zone abbreviation names. There is no standart of custom date and time format string for this names.

Why?

I don't have a perfect answer for this. But I have an answer why there shouldn't be any format for it.

The names of the time zones are not supported by .NET Framework because they are not unique. Different time zones in the world can have the same abbreviation names.

For example `CST` can means 3 different time zone;

- [China Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/asia/cst.html) which is UTC + 8 hours
- [Central Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/cst.html) which is UTC - 6 hours
- [Cuba Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/caribbean/cst.html) which is UTC - 5 hours

So, how `"9 October 2014 20:23:09 CST"` string can be parsed? How .NET Framework can know which time zone information includes this string?

I saw a few articles on internet about this subject and one option (not a good way) can be using this time zone abbreviation name part as a [literal string delimiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and using another [`DateTime.TryParseExact` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes formats as a string array.

```
string s = "9 October 2014 20:23:09 BST";
string[] formats = 
{
    "d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'BST'",
    "d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'EST'"
};
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    //
}
```